# Shiny - uploading a different csv removes the progress from previous csv

Tags: r, csv, shiny, data-wrangling

I think I am missing something when I try to run my shiny app. I am looking for a way to upload a CSV, wrangle the data, and display it as a table. Then if I upload a different CSV, it will wrangle that data and add it to the table without deleting the previous wrangled CSV.

**server.R**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

dat <- data.frame(No. = as.numeric(),
                  Time = as.numeric(),
                  Scramble = as.character(),
                  Date = as.POSIXct(as.character()),
                  Mean = as.numeric())

function(input, output) {

  filedata <- reactive({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    latest <- read_csv2(inFile$datapath) %>% select(-Comment,-P.1)

    if (is.numeric(latest$Time) == TRUE) {
      latest <- latest %>% mutate(Time = Time/1000,
                                  Mean = cummean(Time))
      dat <- rbind(dat, latest)
    } else {
      latest$Time[grepl(":",latest$Time, fixed = T) == F] <- paste("0:",latest$Time[grepl(":",latest$Time, fixed = T) == F], sep="")
      latest <- latest %>% mutate(Time = as.numeric(ms(Time)),
                                  Mean = cummean(Time))
      dat <- rbind(dat, latest)
    }

    return(dat)
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    filedata()

  })
}
```

**ui.R**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
))
```

Can I get some pointers on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`dat <- rbind(dat, latest)` is adding the previous data to the current one. I am not sure why you have added that.

Also , you don't need to initialise the dataframe as well -

```
dat <- data.frame(No. = as.numeric(),
                  Time = as.numeric(),
                  Scramble = as.character(),
                  Date = as.POSIXct(as.character()),
                  Mean = as.numeric())
```

Comment: Im initializing dat and using rbind in the hopes that it will save any previous csv and not overwrite them when i import a new different csv

Comment: When you do `dat <- rbind(dat, latest)` it is going to append `latest` to `dat`. If that is not what you want you should not do it.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I want. The problem is when I upload a new csv, I think it is getting rid of everything in dat and replacing it. I am trying to just add on to the already existing dat.